# Android | Google Maps V2 | Turn By Turn Navigation

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on an android project, in which I need to have feature similar to the one provided by Google Maps Turn-By-Turn Navigation. As far as I have researched, Google Maps V2 API does not provide that feature. Google has Directions API, I am not sure if it can be used to implement a solution similar to turn-by-turn navigation. Is any one aware of some open-source solution or framework which I can use in my android project for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well, They do provide but comes with a price. You need an enterprise level key to use it. 
For you the requirements has to be fulfill so why don't you try with here maps. They provide more features for free. Please visit their site here :

https://developer.here.com/

I am sure you'll find what you're looking for ..